# PythonAnywhere - Telethon - AlwaysOn Task

Tags: pythonanywhere, telethon

I am able to run telethon just fine from P.A. Bash Console.

I have a name.session file saved locally to the directory of my python-telethon script.

Relogging in via bash does not require phone or temp code due to session file.

When I run the script via a task "AlwaysOn" it appears to ignore the session file and requires phone and temp token.

How can I get the P.A. Task to use the session file ?

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 user registered_users 28672 May 30 19:56 name.session
```

.

```
 80 # TELEGRAM ACCOUNT
 81 api_id = config('api_id')
 82 api_hash = config('api_hash')
 83 
 84 async def listener():
 85     async with TelegramClient(session='name.session', api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash) as client:                                                                                     
 86         logger.info("----- LISTENING FOR MESSAGES -----")
 87         print(await client.download_profile_photo('me'))
```

...

````
May 30 20:45:08 2023-05-30 20:45:08,250 - telethon.network.mtprotosender - INFO - Connecting to 149.154.167.51:443/TcpFull...
May 30 20:45:08 2023-05-30 20:45:08,333 - telethon.network.mtprotosender - INFO - Connection to 149.154.167.51:443/TcpFull complete!
May 30 20:45:08 python 3.10.5 (main, Jul 22 2022, 17:09:35) [GCC 9.4.0]
May 30 20:45:08 CCXT Version: 3.1.14
May 30 20:45:08 Traceback (most recent call last):
May 30 20:45:08   File "/home/user/SCRIPT_BABY/main_listener.py", line 143, in <module>
May 30 20:45:08     asyncio.run(main())
May 30 20:45:08   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
May 30 20:45:08     return loop.run_until_complete(main)
May 30 20:45:08   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
May 30 20:45:08     return future.result()
May 30 20:45:08   File "/home/user/SCRIPT_BABY/main_listener.py", line 136, in main
May 30 20:45:08     await listener()  # send image, then
May 30 20:45:08   File "/home/user/SCRIPT_BABY/main_listener.py", line 85, in listener
May 30 20:45:08     async with TelegramClient(session='name.session', api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash) as client:
May 30 20:45:08   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telethon/client/auth.py", line 656, in __aenter__
May 30 20:45:08     return await self.start()
May 30 20:45:08   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telethon/client/auth.py", line 165, in _start
May 30 20:45:08     value = phone()
May 30 20:45:08   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telethon/client/auth.py", line 22, in <lambda>
May 30 20:45:08     phone: typing.Callable[[], str] = lambda: input('Please enter your phone (or bot token): '),
May 30 20:45:08 EOFError: EOF when reading a line
May 30 20:45:09 Please enter your phone (or bot token): ```
````

Answer (score 2):

PythonAnywhere requires an absolute path not a relative path to work with local files.

https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/29172/

Use absolute, not relative paths

One common reason for these kinds of errors is that your working directory settings might be different on PythonAnywhere from your own machine.

The fix is to use the full, absolute path, instead of a "relative" path. So, eg:

/home/yourusername/project-folder/myfile.txt

And not just myfile.txt.